# Time RFC3339 format, to timezone.

Tags: php

I need to convert this time to UTC+00 timezone time. It gives me a date with timezone depending from where user is in RFC3339 format. So it looks like this

```
2000-01-01T00:00:00+02:00
```

I need to use the +02 timezone and correctly calculate the date.
So my idea is: Do I just check what is the last 00:00 and - or + days from the date? Or is there actually functions to use from php side like `time_convert( )` etc..?

I've made this, how ever I am not sure if its correct way of doing it.

```
$date = '2000-01-01 00:00:00+02:00';
$date_date = substr($date, 0, 19);
$add_hours = substr($date, 19, 22)*3600;
$add_mins = substr($date, 23, 25)*60;
$add_secs = $add_hours+$add_mins;
$date = date('Y-m-d H:m:i', strtotime($date_date)+$add_secs);
```

Comment: Look up the `DateTime` class http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.examples-arithmetic.php it has a nice interface for date computing. Try it out and if you have issues you can update your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

gmdate is intended to format GMT(=UTC) output.
See [PHP: gmdate - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gmdate.php)

You may get the result you want by using :

```
$date = strtotime("2000-01-01 00:00:00+02:00");
$utc = gmdate("Y-m-d H:i:sP", $date);
```

where P is the offset with GMT.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use `DateTime` with `DateTimeZone` to get what you're after.

Here's a quick example of how you may use it.

```
<?php


$date = new DateTime('now', new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
$date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('America/Los_Angeles'));

echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); // Converted to LA timezone.
```